# JTAG/SWD Data Logging

Tags: stm32, jtag, debugging, swd

I would like to automatically poll and log certain memory locations on the STM32 I'm working with through the j-link debugger I am using to debug the system. Is this possible through the JTAG or SWD interface? Where should I start looking for more info?

Is it possible to redirect stdout or similar to a file through the j-link?

(STM32F0 w/ IAR IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested I found the [Jlink Software Package](http://www.segger.com/j-link-software.html) and a very useful python wrapper for it at the bottom of [this thread](http://forum.segger.com/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=1545) that were able to do what I was looking for.